# How to remove ints from LinkedList pp = new LinkedList();?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

So I am going to learn trees, but I decided to first learn Linked Lists. In trying to learn LinkedList I found an assignment that wanted me to create a linked list, people going to the bar (with age), and throw out whoever is beneath the age of 18.

I have big problems removing people from my linked list. Everytutorial I can find is using nodes, while I am just interested in using LinkedList (something) = new LinkedList();

So for example, pp.next(); isn't there for me.

The output means:

There is a person of age (number) in line.

This how I want the program to work:

I print out: 
There is a person of age (number) in line.
I remove the people under the age of 18 (I want to remove it in removeAlder method).
I print out again: 
There is a person of age (number) in line (everyone under 18 is removed).

Here is my code.

```
package polkø;


import java.util.*; 
public class Polkø {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random generator = new Random();
        int folk = generator.nextInt(60); 
        folk = folk + 15; 
        personer objekt = new personer(folk); 
        objekt.getAlder(); 

        }



    }






package polkø;

import java.util.*; 

    public class personer {
    LinkedList pp = new LinkedList(); 
    Random generator2 = new Random(); 


    personer(int folk){
    for (int i = 1; i < folk; i++){
        int alder = generator2.nextInt(50); 
        alder = alder + 10; 
        pp.add(alder); 
    }

    }

    public void getAlder(){
    for (int i = 1; i < pp.size(); i++){
    System.out.print("Det står en person i køen som er: "); 
        System.out.print(pp.get(i)); 
        System.out.println(" År gammel"); 

}
    }

    public void removeAlder(){
    for (int i = 1; i < pp.size(); i++){

       //I need something simple here that can remove the people under 18. 

       }

    }
}
```

This is a print out so far:

```
Det står en person i køen som er: 30 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 33 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 13 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 37 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 33 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 45 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 15 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 54 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 20 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 46 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 20 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 10 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 38 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 54 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 31 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 18 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 10 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 16 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 43 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 53 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 38 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 43 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 33 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 15 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 34 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 53 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 38 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 59 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 28 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 32 År gammel
Det står en person i køen som er: 33 År gammel
```

Comment: Can you explain your question more clearly? Your output is not really helpful since most of the people will not be able to understand it.

Comment: Take a look now. I edited. I want my program to do 3 things. Step 1. Print out the people in the linked list (which it does). 2. Remove the people under the age of 18. Print out the same line without the people under the age of 18. I can't find a tutorial online doing this because nobody uses LinkedList (something) = new LinkedList();

Comment: Why have you tagged this with `singly-linked-list`? A `java.util.LinkedList` is doubly-linked; given the question it seems to be irrelevant if it is doubly or singly linked, so no need to tag it.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I thought it was a singly linked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify a list while iterating over it, you will stumble into problems, as the index suddenly is wrong. If you remove a person, the next person does not have index i+1, but suddenly i.

For example:

You are at i = 20, the person is 12. You remove it. Suddenly the list is one shorter and if you continue at 21, you will ignore the person at 20 (which WAS 21 before).

Solution: Use an iterator.

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = pp.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer age = iterator.next();
    if (... your test here) {
        iterator.remove(); // This removes the age from the list AND takes care of updating it, so that the next next() call will work correctly
    }
}
```

Oh, and btw: Classes are capitalized. It's never to early to produce good code instead of just working code ;-)

Comment: I understand I think. Couldn't have I have wrote an if sentence and move all the people one left? Or is it because they are linked I cannot do that, because it will lose the reference? Also, I am going to start to read upon the itorator now, but can I use it for example in arrays as well? I hate removing elements in arrays.

Comment: I do not really understand your question, sorry. If you want to remove all people younger than 18, you don't have much choice but somehow iterate through the list, using a loop.  As for arrays, I would suggest putting the values into a List first ( `new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList ( myArray ) );` ), clean up the list and then retrieve the resulting array (`toArray`...).

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just want to address somethings that were said here and are not entirely true, first of all you CAN remove things on a for loop without using a iterator, yet you shouldn't.

Why? First we need to understand what a LinkedList is.

A LinkedList stores nodes, the nodes store your data. Every node has a `next` and a `previous`. The LinkedList itself only stores 2 of these nods, the first (Head) and the last (Tail).

A LinkedList can't be "freely" accessed like an array, if you have a LinkedList with size 500, and you want to access the 125th element this will cost you time.Basicaly you have to go to the head and do 125 "nexts" until you reach your element. Now this is just for the `get` part if you would do something like

```
if(pp.get(i)<18)
    pp.remove(i);
```

So you have to the a loop "getting the next" `i` times, after you return that the next get will still need, again, "getting the next" `i` times. And the same goes for remove, in order to remove something on a LinkedList you have to first reach that node so again to `remove(i)` you will need to "getting the next" `i` times.

On the other hand, during iteration the last node returned is saved, the next is contant (you only need to do it one time) the remove doesn't waste anytime getting there.

You also seem confused about removal in LinkedList, it isn't the same as in arrays. Just a quick example to help you understand better,

```
A-B-C-D-E
```

and you want to remove C, what happens is

```
B.NEXT = D
D.PREVIOUS = B
C.NEXT = null;
C.PREVIOUS = null;
```